# WordPress Contact form 7 - Fill fields by cookie data

Tags: wordpress, cookies

so my "story" first:

I'm doing a questionaire that is filled by my group every year. To make it easier, I built a page where they can preload the form entries from last year and post them to the questionair.

Currently I am using the multistep addon for CF7 that uses one form/page per step and I'm passing the from data with the dynamic hidden fields from step to step, using the default:post for those fields.
So, e.g. if I have in step 5 a field called "my-field" I'm passing this from step 1 to step 5 with the hidden field, finally in step 5 inserting the value in the field "my-field" so the user can either use the pre-filled value or change it.

I would like to achieve the following:

instead of passing the values through the hidden fields through all steps, I would like to save them to a cookie and make the "real" fields get filled by that cookie data.

I found this solution: https://www.sean-barton.co.uk/2014/04/contact-form-7-place-post-server-cookie-session-variables-fields/
but it also only fills the dynamic hidden fields, so I'd be on the same page again. Only difference would be, that I need per step only add the hidden fields for the next step instead of passing them all through.

So long story short:

How could I manage to fill form fields (a bunch of 20 fields over 9 steps) by the values saved in a cookie?

Thanks a lot!

Best,
Thomas